# Setting constants equal to 1 conditions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, entropy, units, dimensional-analysis, physical-constants

I have the following expression for the entropy of an ideal gas in a microcanonical ensemble,

$$S=Nk_B\ln \left[ \frac{Ve}{N}\left(\frac{4\pi m e E}{3Nh_0^2}\right)\right]
$$

Ideally I would like to get rid of all the constants for my next problem. Are there any conditions on setting all the constants equal to $1$? What do these conditions mean physically if they exist?

Comment: If it's a book-keeping issue, just package the ones you don't want in a single constant and substitute back in at the end...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting constants to be equal to $1$ means that one measures quantities as multiples of that constant. So, for example, if one sets the speed of light, $c$, to $1$, $v=0.5$ means that $v$ amounts to half the speed of light.

It may be clearer, especially to people who are not used to these kinds of conventions, to approach this situation a bit differently; if one wants to measure things in terms of the speed of light $c$ -- whatever value this constant might have in whatever system of units -- one can write $v = 0.5 \cdot c$. This way, the intent is more obvious, dimensional analysis gets easier, and the convention explained above is easily recovered by setting $c=1$ at any later time.

So, if your problem has a characteristic (fixed) volume $V$, you may choose to measure all other volumes as multiples of that $V$. You may do so implicitly by setting $V=1$, in which case you may just omit $V$ from the equation in your question. There are no *conditions* that you absolutely must meet, aside from $V$ being non-zero. However, whether setting some constants equal to $1$ aids your problem or obscures your treatment of your problem may depend on many things, including personal taste.

If you are asking this question because writing out the numerous constants is tedious, you may find it more convenient and clear to just define a new constant. So if $V$, $m$, $e$, and $h_0$ would be uninteresting in large parts of your problem, you may just define $\alpha=\frac{4\pi}{3}Vme^2 h_0^{-2}$ and write
$$
S=Nk_B\ln\left[\frac{\alpha E}{N^2}\right]
$$

Then, after having performed your calculations, you can just insert for $\alpha$ again to get the desired result in the symbols used initially.

Did that answer your question?

Comment: I suppose my question is can $\alpha$ always be set to equal 1

Comment: @1234: Unless $\alpha$ is $0$, or you have made other definitions that would make the definition $\alpha=1$ a contradiction (e.g. by defining the constants $e$, $V$, $m$ and $h_0$ to be $1$ as well), you can set $\alpha=1$, and then drop it from your equations. The price you pay may be clarity, and the fact that you now may be inable to calculate properties that depend on the value of, say, $V$: If you wanted to calculate the pressure from $S=Nk_B\ln(EN^{-2})$ by $P=T\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}$, you'd have no means to derive w.r.t $V$, since it is now "invsible", at least at first glance.